# Elements not resizing equally on mobile device

Tags: android, html, css, resize, html-table

I have a simple page that combines plain text and a table.  Here is the html:

```
<body>
<div id='stat'>
  <p class='subheading'>Stat of the Week: Average Final Standings</p>
  <p class='text'>Each week, I'll be giving a stat from the history of the league. Feel free to suggest any stat you want to see here in future weeks. This week's stat is Average Final Standings. In other words, what is the average finishing place of each owner through the history of the league.  Here are the results:</p>
  <table class='tableBody' style='margin: auto;'>
    <tr class='tableHead'><td colspan='3'>Average Finish</td></tr>
    <tr class='tableSubHead'>
      <td>Team Owner</td><td>Years Played</td><td>Average Place</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='light'>
      <td class='nocenter'>Team #1</td><td>2007-2012</td><td>5.04</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more rows here -->
  </table>

  <p class='text'>Up Next Week: Average Points Per Week</p>
</div>
</body>
```

and the css:

```
body {
  background-image: url(http://g.espncdn.com/s/ffllm/13/images/shell/bgHead.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 14px; 
  margin: 0px; 
  color: #000; 
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tableBody {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width:50%;
}

.nocenter {
  text-align: left;
}

.tableBody td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.tableHead {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #6dbb75;
  text-align: center;
}

.tableSubHead {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #6dbb75;
  text-align: center;
}

.light {
  background-color: #f8f8f2;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #f2f2e8;
}
```

Everything looks great on my laptop browser.  the problem is when I'm viewing the page on my phone.  All of the page looks fine except for the table.  It's tiny!  I have to make the font size almost 3 times larger for it to be the same size on the screen.  Why is this occurring and can I overcome it?

This is on a Samsung Galaxy S2 with the latest Firefox browser (v24).

Update:
I've tried several permutations of px, em, %, etc to no avail.  I can use the workaround proposed in an answer (detecting a mobile browser and specifying a different layout), but I'd like to know the reason for the different rendering of text that is specified as the same font.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the compatible code for the devices as well as browser. You need to detect device and browser, take a look [here](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers%3a_the_RIGHT_way). This [link](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/) will give you some idea, how to make resolution specific style-sheet. This is also a useful [link](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml).

Use [em](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) to define font size is preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links.  But your answer only gives me a workaround.  While a different layout could be helpful (really the only difference in my case would be font size), I'd like to know the cause of the difference in rendering in the two cases.  Specifically why something specified as the same font looks different in a table than it does outside it.

Comment: In other words, this isn't a problem between two devices, but rather on one device.  On the mobile device text that is the same font size is shown as a different size on the screen on the mobile browser.

Comment: If you has chosen to set a minimum font size via mobile browser's configuration, that's may be the problem. can you please check this.

Comment: Aha!  I changed the font size in my browser settings. All the text changed size when I changed this setting EXCEPT the text in the table.  It remains the same size.  Why is that?  Can I get around that?

Comment: Can you inspect the element, which appears wrong and find out the responsible class or Id, &then change value for that class or id.

Comment: When I change the font size of the text in the table, it does change, but not to what the rest of the text is.

Comment: Add a separate class to your table and define text size for that class. It will overwrite the others.

Comment: I tried that also.  No different.  I have to set the table font size to 24px for it to look the same as the body text that is set to 14px.

What appears to be happening is that the mobile browser is overriding the font size of the body text to set it to the user settings size, but it does NOT do so for the table text.